# Scan for all data attributes with the same naming and insert value - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Let's say I have multiple `data-foo="value"` on a page and a `var ID = "12"`. How can I target all instances of that data attribute `foo` on the page and add that `ID` to the end of it, so it becomes `data-foo="value12"`.

The result with a templating engine would be something like `data-foo="value{ID}"`, but I am not using one, just pure JS or jQuery.

The value of `data-foo-"value"` is different throughout the page.

Comment: try with `document.querySelectorAll('[data-foo="value'+id.toString()+'"]');` ... this will find all elements who have attribute data-foo="value{id}", where you have to replace {id} with desired number or whatever

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In according to **MilindAnantwar's** answer.

---

you can using `$('*[data-foo]')` selector to select all elements with attribute `data-foo`, like this:

```
var ID = "12";

$('*[data-foo]').attr( "data-foo", function( i, val ) {
   return val + ID;
});
```

See [**Jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Shady_Alset/xveoad4g/) *(inspect elements and see html code)*

Answer (score 0):

You can target them using attribute equals selector and then modify their values in callback function of `.attr()` method:

```
 var ID = "12";
 $([data-foo="value"]).attr( "data-foo", function( i, val ) {
   return val + ID;
 });
```